# Compare the values of column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Table_1 columns are:

```
======================
A        B
======================
100      4
-----------
101      2
101      3
101      4
-----------
102      6
----------- 
103      7
-----------
104      2
104      3
104      4
-----------
105      2
-----------
106      4
-----------
107      3
--------------------------------
```

Now I have input  B parameter like '6' or '2,3,4'.

I want to get a result like this:

if input B parameter is '6', then output should be:

```
======================
A        B
======================
102      6
```

If input B parameter is '2,3,4', then output should be:

```
======================
A        B
======================
101      2
101      3
101      4
-----------
104      2
104      3
104      4
```

Comment: Really basic question, have you tried anything?

Comment: Are you keeping in mind the order of B?

Comment: I think way of my questioning is wrong. I apologize for that.
I am going to edit the post may be it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the needed columns:

```
SELECT A, B
FROM Table_1
WHERE B IN (2,3,4)
```

EDIT:
If you need them only if all params are present

```
    SELECT A, B
    FROM Table_1
    WHERE A IN (SELECT A FROM Table_1 WHERE B = 2) AND A IN (SELECT A FROM Table_1 WHERE B = 3) AND A IN (SELECT A FROM Table_1 WHERE B = 4)
```

Comment: In this case it will return column 105,106, 107 also.

Comment: @LokeshMasih:- You need to tell, whats the logic for not selecting `105,106, 107`? It looks like when the corresponding column A has similar values then only you want to select. But not sure. Is it so?

Comment: for `105,106,107` you have `243` instead of `234` . Also, the op didn't add `105,106,107` in his expected result

Comment: Because 105,106,107 are not the same value. It should be the same value like 101 or 104

Comment: for the edit, it will work fine but only if parameter is '2,3,4'
If the parameter value is only '2' then it will fail.

Comment: then you should decrease the where conditions

Comment: and you should edit your question. It's not  very clear! You say you can have `2,3,4` or `6` are those the only options or there are other combinations too? Hence the downvotes you are getting (question not that clear and you didn't try to write any code)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one, for your specific requirement -

-- the last digit after = i.e. 3 should be replaced by number of inputs in check  for our case it is 3 for (2,3,4)

```
SELECT A,B FROM Table_1 AS tbl1 WHERE B IN (2,3,4) AND (select COUNT(1) FROM Table_1 AS tbl2 WHERE B IN (2,3,4) AND tbl1.A = tbl2.A)
 = 3
```

Please, have a look.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A
    ,B
FROM table_1
WHERE A IN (
        SELECT A
        FROM table_1
        WHERE B = 2
        )
    AND A IN (
        SELECT A
        FROM table_1
        WHERE B = 3
        )
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer, don't just post the code/query.